# How can i test the heteroscedasticity of time series?

Tags: r, time-series, heteroscedasticity

I'd a problem on testing the heteroscedasticity characteristics of my time series sample with R Studio.

I've tried the McLeod.Li.test to this end but it doesn't work.

Can you inform me if this function is not yet available on R Studio and with what it's replaced because the error text posted was:

```
 Error in McLeod.Li.test(bitcoin): 
  could not find function "McLeod.Li.test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `McLeod.Li.test` function is in the `TSA` package in R. You will need to load the package before the function will work. You can do it as follows:

```
install.packages("TSA")
library(TSA)
McLeod.Li.test(bitcoin)
```

Some more information on the `TSA` library [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSA/versions/1.2.1/topics/McLeod.Li.test).

#### Edit

The `TSA` library has been archived. Find an older version [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/TSA/). Unzip the file, and run the `McLeod.Li.test` function in your global environment. Alternatively you can just copy and paste the function from [here](http://freesourcecode.net/rprojects/8327/sourcecode/McLeod.Li.test.R#.Xz57iTWxW00).

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer

Comment: Sure, did it work for you? @kerkeniwissal

Comment: i'd tried to install the "TSA" package , but it doesn't work. The error text is: Warning in install.packages : package ‘TSA’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)      can you propose to me a solution for this type of error?

Comment: It seems like you will have to update your R and Rstudio to the newest version then. You can do this by installing the ```installr``` package, then loading it ```library(installr)```. Run the command ```updateR()```. This should upgrade you R to the newest version. Let me know if you still have any problems after that :) @kerkeniwissal

Comment: okey , thank you a lot , i will try this and inform you :)

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm disturbing you, but the error text for the TSA package intallation is almost the same: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘TSA’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

Comment: No problem, my mistake I see the TSA package was archived a bit earlier this year. You can find the archived package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/TSA/). Download it, unzip the file and run the ```McLeod.Li.test``` function in your global environment. Hope this works :)